# Powershell: How to Parse the Multi line String as a String parameter?

Tags: sql, powershell, oracle11g

As a newbie in powershell, im trying to read thru a folder which has multiple sql files and iterate them through poweshell scripts read the data from oracle  and export to CSV.

If my sqlfile has a single line statement no issues with the code, its working fine, If my sql file has multiple line statement - as always it has,

the powershell errors out saying 
`"Get-DataTable : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'sql' Cannot convert value to type System.String."`

could you please help me how to resolve this issue? Below my code snapshot.

```
function Get-DataTable{ 
        [CmdletBinding()] 
        Param( 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
            [Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection]$conn, 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] 
            [string]$sql 
        ) 
$cmd = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($sql,$conn) 
$da = New-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataAdapter($cmd) 
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable 
[void]$da.Fill($dt) 
return ,$dt 
} 

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -path $ScriptsDirectory -Filter *.sql | sort-object -desc ) 
{ 
$SQLquery = get-content "$ScriptsDirectory\$file"
echo $SQLquery
$fileName = $file.name.split(".")[0]
$dt = Get-DataTable $conn $SQLquery 
Write-Host "Retrieved records:"  $dt.Rows.Count -ForegroundColor Green
$dt | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -LiteralPath $WorkingDirectory\$fileName.csv
Write-Host "Output Written to :"  $WorkingDirectory\$fileName.csv -ForegroundColor Green    }
```

Comment: `get-content "$ScriptsDirectory\$file"` -> `get-content "$ScriptsDirectory\$file" -Raw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Content` returns an array of lines. If you're using PowerShell v3 or higher you can use the `-Raw` parameter to read the file as one big string:

```
$SQLquery = get-content "$ScriptsDirectory\$file" -Raw
```

Alternatively you could re-join the array with line endings:

```
$SQLquery = $SQLquery -join "`r`n"
```

Or you can read the file all at once with .net classes:

```
$SQLquery = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$ScriptsDirectory\$file")
```